# How does bugfixing work in Android versions?

Tags: android

I'm developing a feature in one of my Android apps, and I want to use a particular WebView API. I have found a bug within this API, which started to exist in version A and was fixed in version B of Android.
What does this mean to me?
Does it mean that people with devices running Android version between A and B will have this bug until their manufacturer decides to provide an update?
Or does it mean that if I build my app using SDK version later than B, it will behave as expected on devices with Android between A and B.

I wasn't able to find an answer to this question online, and based on the [lack of] updates to most of the devices, I think I should not use a function which was bugged on still widely used versions of Android.

An example of what I mean
Bug in WebView discovered in 5.0.1
Bug fixed in 6.0.0
I build using 7.0.0

Does it mean that my app will be affected by the bug?

Comment: Since almost no manufacturers release upgrades, you need to assume any bug in a version you support will effect your app.

Comment: yeah, for example you shouldn't use functions that are deprecated because for newer version it might cause a problem/error. so in these situation, if you must do the work (no go around possible), it is recommend to check mobile version and use proper function accordingly.

Comment: @mehran Nonsense. Seems you do not understand what depreciation really means.

Comment: I appreciate if you could explain it to me.

Comment: I would really appreciate a comment if you downvote this question. Is this question stupid? is this really a common knowledge? I have asked several Android devs and none of them were sure. I understand I might be missing the point of upgrades and the SDK used to build, but I am certain I am not minority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of bugs in Android system, using new system version for build will not fix the issue on the device.
However, in my case - bug in WebView - since Android L, WebView was delivered as a separate package and can be updated without updating Android on the device. Thanks to this, we don't need to wait for manufacturers to release anything, it's up to the user to update their software.